# Ionic prevent hardware back previous page

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to prevent back to previous page via hardware back button by using this:

```
$ionicPlatform.onHardwareBackButton(function () {
    if($state.$current.name=="authentication") {
        $ionicPopup.confirm({
            title: 'System warning',
            template: 'Are you sure you want to exit?'
        }).then(function(res){
           if( res ){
              navigator.app.exitApp();
           }
        })
    }
});
```

But it doesn't work. When the alert popup box appear, it still go back to previous page.

How can I stop it?

Comment: I think my answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32795646/clicking-the-device-back-button-closes-the-app-instead-of-going-back-to-previous/32819358#32819358) can help you.

Comment: @AndreKreienbring Thanks for your comment. But what i want is to prevent it back to previous page & also not exiting the app on certain page.

Comment: That should be perfectly possible by the code I posted as you can decide how you react on the backButtonAction. By removing this line `navigator.app.backHistory();` you prevent the app from going back in History. Also you can ofcourse do that for any $state you like.

Comment: @AndreKreienbring The problem is even with or without `navigator.app.backHistory();`, it will still go back to previous page.

Comment: You can try this  .run(function($ionicPlatform, $ionicPopup) {
  // Disable BACK button on home
  $ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(function(event) {
    if (true) { // your check here
      $ionicPopup.confirm({
        title: 'System warning',
        template: 'are you sure you want to exit?'
      }).then(function(res) {
        if (res) {
          ionic.Platform.exitApp();
        }
      })
    }
  }, 100);
});

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```js
.run(function($ionicPlatform, $ionicPopup) {
  $ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(function(event) {
    if (true && $state.$current.name=="authentication") { // your check here
      $ionicPopup.confirm({
        title: 'System warning',
        template: 'are you sure you want to exit?'
      }).then(function(res) {
        if (res) {
          ionic.Platform.exitApp();
        }
      })
    }
  }, 100);
});
```