# why is hardware back button closing the app on menu screens?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

When I go to any menu page and click on hardware back button , the app closes instead of going to the previous screen? 
I am using

```
<ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="false">
```

Can anybody help me with this?

Note : this happens only with the menu page.

I want the the previous screen to appear when hardware back is pressed. Now, back button just closes the app.

Ionic -v : 1.7.7
cordova -v : 5.3.3

**Update** the problem is with [menu-close](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/menuClose/) directive that is being used in the menu list.

```
  <ion-list>
            <ion-item menu-close nav-clear ui-sref="menu.home">
                    Home
                </ion-item>
                <ion-item menu-close nav-clear ui-sref="menu.welcome">
                    Settings
                </ion-item>
                <ion-item menu-close nav-clear>
                    Profile
                </ion-item>                 
  </ion-list>
```

I replaced that with menu-toggle="left" . Doing this replaces the menu icon with a back key which is undesired. Any way I can make it like all the other native android app behave?

Answer (score 0):

if you like to override your mobile device hadware button you can try this in your controller

```
$ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(function(e) {
    //do your stuff
    if($state.current.name=="login") {
        console.log(e);
     e.preventDefault();
     alert('login');
     //navigator.app.exitApp();
    }
    else{

      $ionicHistory.goBack();

      // in case you find no history just do the following
      // $state.go('previous page state'); this will take you to the page you expected.
    }

    }, 101);
```

It works for particular page but if you like to do it globally you can use it in **.run** function.

here **e.preventDefault();** this one makes your mobile device hardware backbutton disable .

Comment: This code works for me by using the above code you can controll your hardware back button on the current page according to this discussion https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/handling-the-hardware-back-buttons/1505/15 @bengtler it worked for every one i think you have miss placed the code check once

Comment: I am not missing anything here.. its just the menu screens that are creating problems. A hardware back on menu screens closes the app rather than going to the previous screen

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32795646/clicking-the-device-back-button-closes-the-app-instead-of-going-back-to-previous this also the same as you see it worked in here

Comment: Yes i did try that. But if you keep navigating ,things should keep being added in your history. according to that post, the app closes when history is blank. I hope you get the problem. And no where in my code I mentioned an exit.

Comment: in that case you can use $state.go ('next page') check my updated anser

Comment: what is next page?. I think you are still not getting my question. ideally the previous screen should appear ..not the next.

Comment: no i get your point you **next page means** you can give the state of the page you need to go any page you give there it does't matter next page or previous page.

Comment: Please read the update.. I dont think we are on the same page. You are still nt getting the problem. First of all the default behaviour on hardware back button is not to redirect to any page I want, it is to redirect to the previous screen user visited. It is the menu-close that clears the history and thus closing the app. A workaround that is needed. 
Thx for the help,but you are not addressing the problem.